# Conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2

Tags: linux, mono, centos

After repeated attempts and trying to google this issue I'm stuck and am looking for help from my fellow stackers.

Following the [wiki](http://help.tcadmin.com/Mono#CentOS_5.2F6_.2F_Fedora_15_.2F_Redhat_5_64bit) from [tcadmin](http://tcadmin.com) I have to run the following commands

```
wget http://www.tcadmin.com/installer/mono-2.11.4-i386.rpm
yum -y install mono-2.11.4-i386.rpm --nogpgcheck
/opt/mono-2.11.4/bin/mozroots --import --sync --quiet
/opt/mono-2.11.4/bin/mono --aot -O=all /opt/mono-2.11.4/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll
for i in /opt/mono-2.11.4/lib/mono/gac/*/*/*.dll; do /opt/mono-2.11.4/bin/mono --aot -O=all $i; done
```

when I get to the yum part it fails and outputs this error.

```
file / from install of mono-2.11.4-bi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-18.el7.x86_64
```

Most sites and places suggest using an override or force command but this sounds stupid and will probably cause issues down the road for myself and the system.

I have flagged a ticket with the company that supplies the wiki about this issue but I'm yet to have a reply.

Another suggestion was to extract the rpm and move the files one by one but this is quite time consuming..

The ticket was responed to with the following;

> It is safe to force install because all files are placed in /opt/mono-2.11.4 but there is a bug with mono on centos 7 that prevents tcadmin from working correctly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For anyone else who happens upon this thread, I'm pleased to report that while I didn't encounter this error installing mono (that was a whole other process) I did encounter it while trying to install TCAdmin itself, but I was able to complete the installation of TCAdmin on CentOS 7 after using [rpmrebuild](http://rpmrebuild.sourceforge.net/) to modify the spec.

Simply install rpmrbebuild, run `rpmrebuild -pe {packagename}.rpm`, scroll down to the %files section and remove the lines for any offending directories (in my case, the '/' and '/home' directories), save and quit, press y, and note the result location. In my case, it was `/root/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/{packagename}.rpm`.

Traverse to that directory and run `yum -y install ./{packagename.rpm` and it will install without a hitch.

The same should also apply to any other packages that return the conflicts with filesystem error. Just adjust the package names in the above examples accordingly.

*Thanks to the venerable Ahmad Samir for pointing me in the right direction with his post in [this](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/37185/file-conflict-for-installing-a-package-with-filesystem/) thread.

Comment: Seven years on, folks, and this just saved me! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue trying to install Fluentd agent on CentOS 7:

```
(venv)[user@machine01 tmp]$ sudo rpm -ivh td-agent-2.1.1-0.x86_64.rpm 
warning: td-agent-2.1.1-0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID a12e206f: NOKEY
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
    file /opt from install of td-agent-2.1.1-0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-18.el7.x86_64
```

I wouldn't say that downgrading your whole OS is the solution. Maybe an elegant workaround would be to rebuild the .rpm file in order to avoid those file systems which are making conflicts. You can do this by modifying the spec file with rpmrebuild command.

However, if you trust the software you are about to install or you want to try if works no matter what, then an easier (and faster) workaround is to force the rpm installation. That's what I did ...

```
(venv)[user@machine01 tmp]$ sudo rpm -ivh --force td-agent-2.1.1-0.x86_64.rpm 
warning: td-agent-2.1.1-0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID a12e206f: NOKEY
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:td-agent-2.1.1-0                 ################################# [100%]
adding 'td-agent' group...
adding 'td-agent' user...
Installing default conffile...
prelink detected. Installing /etc/prelink.conf.d/td-agent-ruby.conf ...
Configure td-agent to start, when booting up the OS...
```

...and it worked for me

```
(venv)[user@machine01 tmp]$ sudo systemctl start td-agent.service
(venv)[user@machine01 tmp]$ sudo systemctl status td-agent.service
td-agent.service - LSB: td-agent's init script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/td-agent)
   Active: active (running) since vie 2014-12-12 09:34:09 CET; 4s ago
  Process: 17178 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/td-agent start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
...
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Surprisingly since I'm quite new to linux systems outside of git and basic command line stuff, I got this working with your suggestions are there any main cons with this that I might run into down the line?

Answer (score 0):

This is an inherent issue with centos 7.

Going back to centos 6 fixed it.